# traffic shaping

Tags: xen, traffic-shaping

I have a rather complicated set up. So ill try best to explain what i have before i ask the question.

I am sitting at my desktop, ssh'ed to a server(10.10.10.XX). Which has xen guest(10.10.20.XX) installed.. I have on the server installed apache+mediawiki. On the xen guest i have apache installed. I have reversed proxied my xen guests ip to that when you go to 10.10.20.XX/mediawiki it shows the contense of 10.10.10.XX/mediawiki(which is my server).

Heres a diagram:
http://pastebin.com/rCzahxzG

Question:
I want to set the bandwidth of 10.10.20.XX (my domu/guest) to 56KBits. So that when i go to 10.10.20.xx/mediawiki in my browser it takes a 56KBit load time. Which i am not sure if you can do. If not i still want to set my domU guest to 56kbits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wiki2:/# tc qdisc del dev $DEV root
wiki2:/# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 56kbit latency 50ms burst 1540
```

did that in my domu terminal. Works!